# Tor Socks4a Incomplete Response

Tags: c++, networking, proxy, tor, socks

My application requires the use of Tor, over a socks4a proxy. Currently my response from tor is reported as successful but there is no reported Port or Ip, which is required for the 4a variant of socks, according to this wikipedia article [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS4a):

> field 1: null byte
>   field 2: status, 1 byte:
>
> 0x5a = request granted
>   0x5b = request rejected or failed
>   0x5c = request failed
>   0x5d = request failed
>
> field 3: network byte order port number, 2 bytes
>   field 4: network byte order IP address, 4 bytes

Tor is not filling fields 3 and 4, why is it doing this and how can i fix it?

Results of Socks Handshake:

```
Request: 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x77,    
0x77, 0x77, 0x2E, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x67, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x2E, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x00

Response from Tor: 0x00, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

Source Code:

```
retval = connect(in_Socket, in_Socks, socksLen);    //Connecting to Socks Server

    if (retval != 0)
       return retval;                       //Error if !=0

    if (szUserId)
       lPacketLen += strlen(szUserId);   //If there is a userid, add its length to the packet length

    lPacketLen += strlen(szHostName);   //www.google.com
    lPacketLen += 1;
    char *packet = new char[lPacketLen];//Allocate a packet
    memset(packet, 0x00, lPacketLen);   //Init to zero
    packet[0] = SOCKS_VER4;             //Socks version: 0x4
    packet[1] = 0x01;                   //Connect code

    memcpy(packet + 2,(char *)&(((sockaddr_in *)in_szName)->sin_port),2);   //Copy the port, 80 in this case

    //Send a Malformed IP, as per Socks4a states
    packet[4] = 0x00;
    packet[5] = 0x00;
    packet[6] = 0x00;
    packet[7] = 0x8;

    int IDLen = strlen(szUserId);
    if (szUserId)                              //If there was a userid, copy it now
        memcpy(packet + 8, szUserId, ++IDLen); //Account for null terminator /0
    else
        packet[8] = 0; //Send null ID if none provided

    //Write the hostname we want Tor to resolve, i used www.google.com
    memcpy(packet + 8 + IDLen, szHostName, strlen(szHostName) + 1);

    if (m_Interval == 0)
        Sleep(SOCKS_INTERVAL);
    else
        Sleep(m_Interval);

    printf("\nRequest: ");
    PrintArray(packet, lPacketLen);


    send(in_Socket, packet, lPacketLen, 0); //Send the packet
    delete[] packet;        //Unallocate the packet

    char reply[8];          //Allocate memory for the reply packet
    memset(reply, 0, 8);    //Init To 0

    long bytesRecv = 0;
    bytesRecv = recv(in_Socket, reply, 8, 0);   //Get the reply packet

    printf("\nResponse from Tor: ");
    PrintArray(reply, 8);

    //Check Reply Codes later
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Tor treats this as an optional field, it seems to remember the connection address, resolve it, then forward any data after the handshake to the resolved domain.